# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JobRepository is mandatory

Tags: spring-batch

I am a beginner with spring batch, and I developped a simple project with it . I am getting the error.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JobRepository is mandatory

I followed the Spring official website for it but its still giving the error
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Here is the Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jobs")
public class JobController {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    
    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion;
    
    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public Map getStatus() {
        Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("app-version", appVersion);
        return map;
    }


    @PostMapping("/importCustomers")
    public void importCsvToDBJob() {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("startAt", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Job Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SpringBatchConfig {
    
    private CustomerRepository repo;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/customers.csv"));
        itemReader.setName("csvReader");
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        return itemReader;
    }

    private LineMapper<Customer> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<Customer> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames("id", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "gender", "contactNo", "country", "dob");

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Customer> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Customer.class);

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;

    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerProcessor processor() {
        return new CustomerProcessor();
    }

   
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
      return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_INFO (CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, GENDER, CONTACT, COUNTRY, DOB) VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :email, :gender, :contactNo, :country, :dob)")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer) {
          return new StepBuilder("step1")
            .<Customer, Customer> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
        }
    
    @Bean
    public Job importCustomers(JobRepository jobRepository,
        JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
      return new JobBuilder("importCustomers")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(listener)
        .flow(step1)
        .end()
        .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }

}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'job'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'importCustomers' defined in class path resource [com/javatechie/spring/batch/config/SpringBatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'importCustomers' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'step1' defined in class path resource [com/javatechie/spring/batch/config/SpringBatchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'step1' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JobRepository is mandatory
```

Kindly suggest what changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the job repository when creating jobs and steps with their respective builders:

```
    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer) {
          return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository) // here
            .<Customer, Customer> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
        }
    
    @Bean
    public Job importCustomers(JobRepository jobRepository,
        JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
      return new JobBuilder("importCustomers", jobRepository) // here
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(listener)
        .flow(step1)
        .end()
        .build();
    }
```

You should have a deprecation warnings for those constructors that do not accept the job repository as parameter.

Comment: He already uses the new Builders as you suggest.

Comment: Yes, but he is not specifying the job repository as a second parameter as shown in this answer, hence the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: JobRepository is mandatory` error.

Comment: ok I see now. will remove my -1 when I am able to